# Instance does not appear in shell

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

I'm currently learning Python and I'm very confused with its behaviour. I'm creating an instance of a class and calling it directly. It is not appearing on the shell when I'm executing the script, only when I'm calling it directly in the shell. Why does Python behave like that or is it a problem with IDLE?

Here's the code of foo.py:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, _data=None):
        self.data = _data

    def __repr__(self):
        return "repr[%s]" % self.data

    def __str__(self):
        return "str[%s]" % self.data


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print "Begin"

    f = Foo(1234)

    print "direct"
    f

    print "print"
    print f 

    print "End"
```

Here's the shell output:

```
Begin
direct
print
str[1234]
End
>>> f
repr[1234]
>>>
```

Btw. I'm on linux (ubuntu 16.04 LTS) using IDLE 2.7.12 with Python 2.7.12

Comment: Typing an object's name in a shell will display the object, but in a script it does nothing.

Comment: What you are calling "the shell" is a REPL - Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop. It prints the result of evaluating the last expression/block. Outside of a REPL, you need to tell Python to do the printing, or else it wont.

Comment: What you observe is intended Python behavior.  IDLE just redirects the standard output, normally displayed in a text console, to a GUI window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr. Gordon pointed out in his comment the REPL will print the object, but in the script it won't print it out unless you tell it to do so. If you want the same type of behavior as the REPL you can do:

```
print(repr(f))
```

That should give you:

```
repr[1234]
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That's what I wanted. It's hard to debug my code if I don't see what an object returns. Now it's more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't just type in an object an expect it to print. You need to tell python to print it. The shell is different and is designed to always print the output.